# how to group by data in highcharts based on two categories?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I have created highchart in that i have to display data based on two group by condition but i am not able to group by based on that.
Here is my data, in this i have to group by based on countType and duration (x-axis:date ,y-axis:count), i have created fiddle as well.Please help.ANy help would be highly appreciated.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p7tjm4r9/21/

```
[
    {
        "count": 40,
        "countType": "DISCHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-11",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 27,
        "countType": "CHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-11",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 23,
        "countType": "CHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-12",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 23,
        "countType": "CHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-14",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 40,
        "countType": "DISCHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-13",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "countType": "DISCHARGEVOLTAGE",
        "date": "2021-06-11",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "countType": "DISCHARGEVOLTAGE",
        "date": "2021-06-13",
        "duration": "ST-15"
    },
    {
        "count": 40,
        "countType": "DISCHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-11",
        "duration": "EV1"
    },
    {
        "count": 40,
        "countType": "DISCHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-13",
        "duration": "EV1"
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "countType": "DISCHARGE",
        "dates": "2021-06-11",
        "duration": "EV1"
    },
    {
        "count": 6,
        "countType": "CHARGE",
        "date": "2021-06-11",
        "duration": "EV1"
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "countType": "CHARGE",
        "dates": "2021-06-12",
        "duration": "EV1"
    },
]
```

Comment: share expected output screenshot

Comment: I am not able to decide how to show based different duration and counttype, that's why i am stuck on this, count and duration is displaying but bar is of same color , so not able to differentiate for which duration it is showing

Comment: It's hard to find the best solution without getting to know your requirements. Check the grouped-categories plugin https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/ and stacked and grouped columns demo : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped . Let me know if any of these is would be adequate for your data example